# Angular reactive form, how to know if valueChanges is triggered by user?

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms

When subscribing valueChanges event, sometimes I want to handle the event only when the change is triggered by user, not by pathValue or setValue.

I know patchValue have a option `emitEvent: false`, but that will skip the whole event for all subscribers, and cause some operators like `pairwise` not working appropriately as well

Is there anyway to know who (user or code) trigger the event in valueChanges?

Comment: Is this just for one control, or for a whole form? Can you share some code.

Comment: In options, you have `emitEvent` and `onlySelf` [angular documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/9.1.3/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L630)